# Is it possible to clear a form and reset (reload) the page with one button?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I've got a form on a page where the user types something in and then a result is returned and displayed on the page. Is it possible for me to have a button that will both, clear the search results and the form simultaneously?

I know that you can use the `<input type="reset" value="Reset"/>` button on the form to reset the form and also use the following code, to reload the page.

`<input type="button" value="Clear Results" onClick="window.location.reload()">`

Is it possible to have the button do both things i.e. clear the search results and reset the form? Can it be done using JavaScript, if so how?

Thanks

Comment: `<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">` or am I missing something?

Comment: Doesn't reloading the page reset everything?

Comment: @Mimisbrunnr No, it doesn't. Try for yourself -- type something into the search box at the top of this page and hit refresh. Your value is still there. rockerest's solution should work

Comment: But is that the actual standard for what should happen? or is that your browzer being "helpful"

Comment: @katspaugh Yep http://jsfiddle.net/gZEUG/. @Mimisbrunnr Not sure, but it does happen -- so it needs to be handled.

Comment: Would not it be easier to just remove the search results `div` instead of reloading the page?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want the functionality of both of the snippets you posted, you can simply combine them.

```
<input type="reset" value="Reset" onClick="window.location.reload()">
```

Comment: Don't use inline JavaScript, it's a hell to maintain.

Answer (score 17):

I'm a fan of @MikeyHogarth's suggestion since it's called regardless of how the page is refreshed. This is one of those rare times that I find straight javascript to be simpler than jquery so I just wanted to add the code for that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    resetForms();
});

function resetForms() {
    document.forms['myFormName'].reset();
}
```

This uses the form name attribute, and if you'd prefer using the form id attribute use this instead:

```
document.getElementById('myFormId').reset();
```

Answer (score 6):

using JQuery, do something like this on the page;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    resetForms();
});

function resetForms() {
    for (i = 0; i < document.forms.length; i++) {
        document.forms[i].reset();
    }
}
```

and then just use your second input, forms will auto refresh when the page loads back up.

Answer (score 4):

you can simply redirect page to current location with this code:

```
$('[data-command="reset"]').click(function () {    
    window.location.href = window.location.href;
}
```

---

```
<input type="button" value="Clear Results" data-command="reset">
```

Answer (score 0):

Isn`t it better like this in vanilla javascript?

```
<button onclick="window.location.href = window.location.href">Reload website and reset forms</button>
```

Comment: Better than what?

Comment: @LajosArpad than doing complicated script like other suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have a button that both clears the search results and resets the form using JavaScript. You can achieve this by writing a custom JavaScript function that clears the search results and resets the form elements. Here's how you can do it:

```js
function searchFunction() {
}

function clearResultsAndResetForm() {
  document.getElementById('searchResults').innerHTML = '';
  document.getElementById('myForm').reset();
}
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="text" id="searchInput" name="search" placeholder="Search">
  <input type="button" value="Search" onclick="searchFunction()">
</form>

<div id="searchResults">
</div>

<input type="button" value="Clear Results and Reset Form" onclick="clearResultsAndResetForm()">
```

I hope this will help fix your problem :)