# How to force reload a form in IE

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form. When I click Refresh in browser, form options stay cached in IE. How can I programmatically force page reload with JS or JQ?

Comment: `$(":input").val("")` ?  - EDIT: `form.reset()` is the way to go as per linked dupe questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset (clear) form through javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786694/how-to-reset-clear-form-through-javascript)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to clear a form an reset (reload) the page with one button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666363/is-it-possible-to-clear-a-form-an-reset-reload-the-page-with-one-button)

Comment: @SmokeyPHP - you gotta be kidding me?!?!?

Comment: @bPratik Nope, just completely forgot about `form.reset()` ROFL - will at least work on inputs that aren't in forms, so.. might as well leave it there

Comment: Take a look at this SO answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13707898/791952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, you'd use [`form.reset()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/form.reset) as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786702/476786)

with jQuery:

```
$('form')[0].reset();
```

Or without jQuery:

```
document.forms[0].reset();
```

Having said that, if those values that you see are being prefilled by the browser as part of it's autocomplete feature, you can disable it by using the techniques suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/582292/476786):

Form level:

```
$('form').attr( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

Individual element level:

```
$('inputSelector').attr( "autocomplete", "off" );
```

Answer (score 1):

Plain javascript:

```
form.reset();
```

You can access your form like this

```
var form = document.forms["your_form_name"];
```

To perform this on every page reload wrap it in **onload** event handler, like this:

**jQuery** (the easiest one)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    document.forms["your_form_name"].reset();
});
```

or plain **javascript**

```
var form = document.forms["your_form_name"];
var handler = function () {
    form.reset();
};

if (form.addEventListener) {
    form.addEventListener("load", handler, false);
} else if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("onload", handler);
} else {
    form["onload"] = handler;
}
```

or

```
<body onload="document.forms['your_form_name'].reset();">
    (...)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use JS to do this: window.location.reload()

Comment: That's reloading the page, not the form's input values