# Reload page not working after validation using JS

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, reload

So I have a form that has Laravel validation on it. Page reload is working well if there're no problems with the form such as required fields, but if validation fails, the reload page is not working. I am forcing the page to reload if the back button is clicked. Here's the code have.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('form').get(0).reset();
    });
</script>
```

All fields should be blank after successful submission.
What should be the other things to do to achieve it in laravel blade file?

Comment: if you are not sending with ajax, then page must be refresh on proper request. it means form fields should be empty after page refresh

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `location.reload();` ?

Comment: Yes, it was my first solution but the same result as what I'm using.

Comment: have you tried out this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666363/is-it-possible-to-clear-a-form-and-reset-reload-the-page-with-one-button. The one answered by Chaya Cooper seems similar to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.
I have done it this way:

```
<script>
    if (!!window.performance && window.performance.navigation.type === 2) {
        //navigation type 2 is accessed using back button while, 
        //0 is accessed using the link or redirected after validation and 1 is refresh page
        window.location.reload();
    }
</script>
```